# Zend Framework Serialization of Closure not allowed

Tags: php, zend-framework, closures, zend-framework3

I'm having difficulty finding an answer to this issue specifically for zend framework on the internet.

I'm getting an error of `Serialization of Closure is not allowed`.

The issue I have is that its just the zend internal code, not any of my code. I know this because i used the zend skeleton application.

Here's the debug output:

```
     ! ) Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in /var/www/html/foundation-project/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php on line 81
    Call Stack
    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
    1   0.0093  356288  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
    2   0.0204  560632  Zend\Mvc\Application::init( YToyOntzOjc6Im1vZ... )  .../index.php:40
    3   0.0695  1047512 Zend\Mvc\Application->bootstrap( YTowOnt9 ) .../Application.php:271
    4   0.0935  1170496 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent( TzoxNzoiWmVuZFxNdmNcTXZjRXZlbn.HJvcGFnYXRpb24iO2I6MDt9 )  .../Application.php:159
    5   0.0939  1170496 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners( cjoxODk7, ??? )   .../EventManager.php:171
    6   0.0944  1171848 Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ViewManager->onBootstrap( cjoxODk7 ) .../EventManager.php:322
    7   0.0991  1175752 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get( czoyODoiSHR0cERlZmF1bHRSZW5kZXJpbmdTdHJhdGVneSI7 ) .../ViewManager.php:103
    8   0.0991  1175752 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate( czo0MzoiWmVuZFxNdmNcVmlld1xIdHRwXERlZmF1bHRSZW5kZXJpbmdTdHJhdGVneSI7, ??? )   .../ServiceManager.php:200
    9   0.0992  1176184 Zend\Mvc\Service\HttpDefaultRenderingStrategyFactory->__invoke( cjoyNTA7, czo0MzoiWmVuZFxNdmNcVmlld1xIdHRwXERlZmF1bHRSZW5kZXJpbmdTdHJhdGVneSI7, Tjs= )  .../ServiceManager.php:764
    10  0.1001  1176976 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get( czoxNDoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFZpZXciOw== ) .../HttpDefaultRenderingStrategyFactory.php:27
    11  0.1001  1176976 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate( czoxNDoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFZpZXciOw==, ??? )   .../ServiceManager.php:200
    12  0.1002  1177400 Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewFactory->__invoke( cjoyNTA7, czoxNDoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFZpZXciOw==, Tjs= )  .../ServiceManager.php:764
    13  0.1018  1180248 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get( czozODoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFN0cmF0ZWd5XFBocFJlbmRlcmVyU3RyYXRlZ3kiOw== ) .../ViewFactory.php:29
    14  0.1018  1180248 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate( czozODoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFN0cmF0ZWd5XFBocFJlbmRlcmVyU3RyYXRlZ3kiOw==, ??? )   .../ServiceManager.php:200
    15  0.1019  1180672 Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewPhpRendererStrategyFactory->__invoke( cjoyNTA7, czozODoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFN0cmF0ZWd5XFBocFJlbmRlcmVyU3RyYXRlZ3kiOw==, Tjs= )   .../ServiceManager.php:764
    16  0.1023  1181784 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get( czozMDoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFJlbmRlcmVyXFBocFJlbmRlcmVyIjs= ) .../ViewPhpRendererStrategyFactory.php:25
    17  0.1023  1181784 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate( czozMDoiWmVuZFxWaWV3XFJlbmRlcmVyXFBocFJlbmRlcmVyIjs=, ??? )   .../ServiceManager.php:200
    18  0.1098  1277080 Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig->Zend\Mvc\Service\{closure}( cjoyNTA7, cjoxOw== ) .../ServiceManager.php:779
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. **Maybe i have some software in my ubuntu distribution thats prohibiting me from this**

Comment: It's PHP that can't serialize closures. You're getting this error because ZF is trying to serialize (cache) a config file that contains a closure.

Comment: @TimFountain OK So what do I have to do to get this running. Its a bare skeleton application so im not sure what i need to do to get this fixed.

Comment: @TimFountain I dont see any closures anywhere in the skeleton application config

Comment: PHP was at 7.1. Needs to be at 7.2